VSC Intellisense not parsing Sphynx docstrings
If i press ctrl+space on a function with a Sphinx formatted docstring
def example_function(param1: int, param2: str) -> bool:
    """
    Processes data.
    :param param1: The first parameter (integer).
    :param param2: The second parameter (string).
    :return: True if successful, otherwise False.
    :rtype: bool
    """
    return True

i get:

Where for example with numpy formatting i get a correct formatting like:

I remember clearly to be able to see Sphinx formatting in the past.
Has anything changed? I need to configure something? (Python 3.13)
